# Spring Security 5.1.1 OAuth2 Client connecting to spring-security-oauth2 Auth Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

This is a little specific, so pardon if this goes on a bit.  I have a project that was using Spring Boot 1.x and it's version of Spring Security.  We use OAuth2 for user login, so we have been using the separate spring-security-oauth2 library to provide filters, etc for oauth clients and resource servers.  We could interact with multiple Auth Servers, one of which is an implementation of the Authorization server provided by a reference sample in spring-security-oauth2.  This returned a JWT which contained the granted authorities embedded within the JWT itself.  It wasn't using OpenID Connect or anything like that.

Now, we are upgrading to Spring Boot 2, with the new version of Spring Security.  And now the support for OAuth2 Client Login is part of Spring Security and the spring-security-oauth2 client is no longer needed.  And this is working great of the Auth Servers we interact with that support OpenID Connect.  I've been able to use the samples/boot/oauth2login sample code in the Spring Security repo, add our OpenID Connect Auth Server, and it all works really easy.

However, we still have some test environments that use our reference Auth Server Implementation for it's credentials, etc.  I am struggling to get the Sample code to work.  If I simply add the new client registry in the sample's Application.yml file....

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: 107403879208-ctufv96i3pchbc1ha9hjsv45efvne1ql.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: Ew8jzBhn3z9l1Gf-fgqOijg9
          github:
            client-id: 6369a4bc4a03714bdba7
            client-secret: 5caced75c09cdcb3288d89f2947248578ea5e01a
          facebook:
            client-id: your-app-client-id
            client-secret: your-app-client-secret
          okta:
            client-id: your-app-client-id
            client-secret: your-app-client-secret
          myauthserver:
            client-name: MyAuthServer
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/myauthserver
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
            token-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys
          myauthserver:
            authorization-uri: http://<snip>.com/uaa/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://<snip>.com/uaa/oauth/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://<snip>.com/uaa/oauth/token_key
```

The web page displays, and I can log into the remote auth server, but I get the error "[missing_user_info_uri] Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: myauthserver" after a successful login.  This error is coming from the DefaultOAuth2UserService.  It looks like the default behaviour is to call back out to the UserInfo endpoint for the claims.

However, for this AuthServer, it doesn't have a userInfo endpoint (at least I don't think it does).  The JWT returned by the AuthServer embeds the granted authorities in the token.  So, what I would like to do is provide my own service to parse the token and do it myself.  [According to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oauth2-user-service), I should be able to.  So, I have added some additional configuration to the sample code

```
package sample.config;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;

import java.util.Collections;


@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(this.customOAuth2UserService());
    }

    private OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> customOAuth2UserService() {
        return new CustomOAuth2UserService();
    }

    private class CustomOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

        @Override
        public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
            System.out.println("-->  In loadUser");
            return new DefaultOAuth2User(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyMap(), "");
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I could parse the token myself and load the Oauth2User from the data which is already in the JwtToken which has been returned to the application.  The above code doesn't do that yet, but I was hoping I could use that service to start parsing the JWT which has already been returned

However, when I attempt to do this, I get this error just attempting to view the page I was able to see before.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Client Registration Identifier. It must be provided via @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("client1") or @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient(registrationId = "client1").
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.method.annotation.OAuth2AuthorizedClientArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(OAuth2AuthorizedClientArgumentResolver.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

I've tried to use that annotation in places in the web security adapter, but I've had no luck.  The moment I attempt to provide a custom userService, it all falls apart.

Sorry for the length of this.  Am I doing anything obviously wrong?  I've been stuck on this for a few days now.  It seems like I should be able to provide the OAuth2Service that can parse the JWT in order to populate the GrantedAuthorities for the OAuth2User.  But it's just not working for me.  Again, I have been using the existing sample code in the spring-security repo (I've branched off of master, rebasing just today).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten past this answer.  If I look at what the auto configuration does (which is contained in OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration class... which is called from the OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration annotation), you can see how it sets up the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should one be missing....

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class)
static class OAuth2WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login()
                .and().oauth2Client();
    }

}
```

So, if I change my code to use a Configuration annotation (instead of an EnableWebSecurity annotation) as well as add the similar calls to authorizeRequests, I don't get the error and I can call out to my authServer

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(this.customOAuth2UserService());
    }
```

It took some sifting through the code and remembering to see what the auto config does, but I should be able to progress now